# Struct with multiple arrays which size is defined in execution time

Tags: c, arrays, struct

What I would like to have, is a `struct` like this:

```
struct Store{
    int client_debts[];
    struct items[];
};
```

When the execution begins, the program read an input file that defines the size of the arrays in that `struct`, so i could do something like this:

```
struct Store s;
int client_debts[defined_size];
s.client_debts = client_debts;
```

How can I achieve that?

**PD:** I tried using pointers in the `struct` and then assigning them the arrays, but when the function that created the arrays ended, the array memory is liberated so the pointer keeps pointing to a unassigned memory thus creating segmentation faults.

Comment: You should use dynamic mem to do this, the dynamic mem is never out of scope so it will never be freed until you do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to do what you want is to allocate them dynamically:

```
struct Store{
    int             *client_debts;
    struct mystruct *items;
};

struct Store store;
int n;

scanf ("%d", &n);
if (n <= 0)
   error_message();

store.client_debts = malloc (sizeof (*store.client_debts) * n);
store.items        = malloc (sizeof (*store.items) * n);
if (!store.client_debts  ||  !store.items)
   error_message();
```

Even though they are pointers, they will act exactly like the arrays of your original declaration.

Comment: maybe you meant sizeof(int) * n?; same with other variable

Comment: ...or even `sizeof (*store.client_debts) * n`

Comment: @giorgi:  Nope.  The way I wrote it has the greatest resistance to errors introduced during modification.  What if the type of those fields are changed?